# WSO2 Integration Studio - cannot configure proxy

Tags: proxy, configuration, wso2

I am working with WSO2 Integration Studio 6.5.0 and encountered mysterious behavior when trying to configure proxy. On one of the computers everything works fine, permitting to add new mediators to the canvas.

[image: example of the proper behavior]

The same version in Integration Studio, configured with the same version of JDK (10.0), used on another computer does not permit to add mediators to the canvas.

[image: example of wrong behavior.]

I have verified the identity of the Eclipse, Java and system configuration to the possible extent and could not find any differences.
I will need to make the development environment available for a wider group of developers, so being able to port it to other computers is important.
I shall appreciate any hypotheses and recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved - just add option:

-Dswt.autoScale=100

to IntegratioStudio.ini.